# Am I need to differentiate expected value and variance in BatchNorm backward implementation?

Tags: python, torch

I'm implementing BatchNorm layer now. I use `Module` as base class, but change some methods -- for forward-pass and backward-pass:

```py
class BatchNormalization(Module):
    EPS = 1e-3
    def __init__(self, alpha = 0.):
        super(BatchNormalization, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.moving_mean = 0
        self.moving_variance = 0
        
    def updateOutput(self, input):
        if self.training:
            batch_mean = input.mean(axis=0)
            batch_variance = input.var(axis=0)
            self.output = (input - batch_mean)/np.sqrt(batch_variance + self.EPS)
            self.moving_mean = self.moving_mean * self.alpha + batch_mean * (1 - self.alpha)
            self.moving_variance = self.moving_variance * self.alpha + batch_variance * (1 - self.alpha)
        else:
            self.output = (input - self.moving_mean)/np.sqrt(self.moving_variance + self.EPS)
        return self.output
    
    def updateGradInput(self, input, gradOutput):
        # since math expectation and variance both are functions w.r.t x, we need to diff it as functions
        diff_input_1 = np.full(input.shape, (input.shape[1] - 1)/input.shape[1])*np.sqrt(input.var(axis=0) + self.EPS)

        diff_input_2 = (input - input.mean(axis=0)) * (input - 1/input.shape[1]) / input.shape[1]/np.sqrt(input.var(axis=0) + self.EPS)
        self.gradInput = gradOutput* (diff_input_1 - diff_input_2)/(input.var(axis=0) + self.EPS)
        return self.gradInput
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "BatchNormalization"
```

So, my backward pass (using `updateGradInput()` func) produces wrong output (compared to output of `torch.nn.BatchNorm1d()` ). Question is: am I need to differentiate $\mathbb{E}(x)$ and $\mathbb{D}(x)$ as functions of $x$? Reminder: batchorm is transformation such as: $$y = \frac{x - \mathbb{E}(x)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{D}(x) + \varepsilon}}$$ (eps here for avoiding comp. problems).

My result is: $$y = \frac{(\frac{n-1}{n}, ..., \frac{n-1}{n})*\sqrt{\mathbb{D}x + \varepsilon} - (x - \mathbb{E}x)\frac{1}{n}(x - \frac{1}{n})/\sqrt{\mathbb{D}x + \varepsilon}}{\mathbb{D}x + \varepsilon},$$
where $n$ is the length of the $x$ vector (or num of features (columns) if $x$ is matrix).
Is this correct?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen r u sure that my question is about software? You may want to check my question again and see